# why we cannot integrate on a nonorientable manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, integration

I feel it rather weird that there is a notion of integration when you glue a patch of paper to  get a surface of cylinder while there is not a suitable notion when you glue it differently to get a Moebius band. Should not a Moebius band have a definite area??

Comment: I don't remember the details, but there is a notion of integration on nonorientable manifolds. You could always integrate on the orientation cover, but you can also define modified top dimensional differential forms by setting $|\Lambda^n(M)|$ the orientable real line bundle obtained from the cocycle $|\det(Jac)|$ the determinant of the jacobian matrices associated to a chart, you can even define $|\Lambda^n(M)|^p$ for $1\leq p<\infty$ with the cocycle $|\det(Jac)|^p$. There is then a natural way to "integrate the $p$-th power of sections of this bundle.

Comment: Or you could remove a measure-zero subset making $M$ orientable.